# Compare dates by interval name

Tags: javascript, date, compare, intervals

I am facing the issue of comparing dates by interval in Javascript.

I have to use interval names such as `1 year`, `6 months` etc which are hard coded in a database to compare them against `now()` to see if a selected date is within this interval.

I cannot seem to find any function that can do this. Something like

`now() + interval '1 year'` in PostgreSQL

Comment: You will need to use a library for this ... a good options is [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: no you done need any libraries....i would just use timestamps. get the "start timestamp" and the "end timestamp" from your interval and look, if the "now()" timestamp is between the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods that get and set the date components.

Example:

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 6);
document.write(d);
```

Setting a component to a value that is out of range will adjust the other components to form a correct date. If you for example add six months in october so that you set a month number of 15, it will automatically wrap to the next year and set the month to april.

Using a string like `"6 months"` would simply be a matter of parsing the string and doing the correct manipulation. Example:

```
var d = new Date();
var s = '6 months';

var p = s.split(' ');
var n = parseInt(p[0], 10);
switch (p[1]) {
  case 'year':
  case 'years': d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + n); break;
  case 'month':
  case 'mongths': d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + n); break;
  case 'day':
  case 'days': d.setDate(d.getDate() + n); break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow the question correctly, you could use JavaScript Date methods `getFullYear`, `getMonth`, etc, with a bit of logic:

```js
var datestring = "1992-06-22"; 
var d = new Date(datestring); // date from sql

var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();

if (year == 2015)
   document.write("This year");
else if (year > 2005)
   document.write("Within last ten years")
else if (year > 1965)
   document.write("Within last fifty years")

if (year == 2015 && month < 6)
   document.write("First six months of this year")

//and so on
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uuy2d2fk/